# how do I add a calculator to my chatbot

Tags: javascript, web

I have a chatbot (javascript) that works according to my written answers, I enter a command that has a keyword, go through the input written and if the keyword is find the chatbot responds with a code written according to my answer. I need help to make my chatbot have the ability to calculate simple math problems (+,-,*,/).

Comment: What is your actual problem? Symbols to math functions ?

Comment: Share what you have tried so far and also share the problem you are having with that try.

Comment: i = 0;
 while (i < vocab.length) {
  var mb = "<br/><span style='color: #4DB9E7;'>Zing:</span> ";
  var n = userInput.includes(vocab[i]);
  
  if (n === true) {
   chatbox.innerHTML += mb + ans[i];
   break;
  }
  
  i++;

  if (n === false && i === vocab.length) {
   chatbox.innerHTML += mb + "Sorry, I can't understand! check your message and send again please!";
  }
 }
 document.getElementById("userInput").value = '';
}

Answer (score 0):

Take the value from the chat, in this case a command to calculate, say `[calc](calculationhere)` then parse the equation with a library. A simple search will yield many javascript calculation parsers for simple operations like with that fashion.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I did not understand how can I get the value of the input for example "6+8". (I don't want to have to enter more than one question to get the problem's answer). can you give me an example of your idea in code?